# avoid dups in stateProvider resolve angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, code-duplication, resolve

I have data that need to be refreshed before the user enter to each view.
I have abstract state "course", and if I resolve the data just in that abstract state, the data didn't refreshed when routing between sub views.

```
state('course', {
            url: '/course/:courseId',
            abstract: true,
            resolve: {
                courseId : ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                    return $stateParams.courseId;
                }],
                editions : ['courseId', 'ApiSvc', function(courseId, api){
                    return api.editionsList(courseId);                     
                }]
            },
```

now, i want the editions to resolve (and be updated) in state 'course.answers','course.questionnaire.questions' and in 'course.questionnaire.editions', so i can repeat this resolve in their state, but how can I resolve same data in multiple states, so it will be updated, and without long duplication of code?
thanks!

Comment: Why not using a service to hold this data, each relevant controller will call service's update data method?

Comment: because i want to resolve the data before enter to view. and also, if i understand you - you just move the dups to other place, no?

Comment: What I suggested is to have the data with its update logic on the service injected to all relevant controllers. This way each controller will have to call the update method on its resolve but you wont need to maintain the duplicated logic in all controllers.

Comment: i dont understand - if i inject into controller service that have method to update data - the data still not updated, until i'll call this method. i'm wrong?

Comment: That is right, but if you call this method on the child's controller initialisation the data will be available to the view immediately.

Comment: "the child's controller initialisation" is the "resolve", i'm wrong? this is exactly what i did - in the resolve i called a method in service that return that data. can you give me example?